# LinearLayout cropping but not expanding in Scrollview

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

Hee guys,

I've been searching here and there but can't seem to find the solution. I'm using a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView inside a LinearLayout, LinearLayout -> ScrollView -> LinearLayout. However it doesn't expand when I want to, instead it crops my layout.

Anyone know what I'm missing here? Might be a bit messy, but been trying alot of stuf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/image_slider_menu"
            layout="@layout/image_slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/menu"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bars_map"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/maps" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/report"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:text="Meld Misbruik"
                android:clickable="true" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/bar_view_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="title"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/bar_view_description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="description"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/menu"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Contact"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/bar_view_contact"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Gegevens" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Changed it as you guys suggested. It is expanded (Text dissapears at the bottom), but I can't scroll there. 

I'm gonna go home now, I'll check with this later. Anyway thanks!

Comment: The problem is the weight values. I removed them al, gave some heights and wrap contents and now it is scrolling again.... However this doesn't make it responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the weight values. I removed them al, gave some heights and wrap contents and now it is scrolling again.... However this doesn't make it responsive.

This does answer my question, but doesn't require what I want. However the layout looks good enough, even on different resolutions so thats why I leave it like this.

Answer (score 0):

nothing missed, it's proper way to behave, unfortunately... your LinearLayout should have wrap_content without weight, check this: [ScrollView's Handy Trick](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/)

also you might measure both SCrollView and Linear and if svHeight>llHeight then ll.getLayoutParams().height=sv.height

edit:
ok, some handy code for you:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
...
```

in code:

```
sv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<16)
                sv.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
//misspell :D
            else
                sv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            int svHeight=sv.getMesuredHeight();
            if(svHeight>ll.getMeasuredHeight())
                ll.getLayoutParams().height=svHeight;
        }
}
```

Comment: Which linear? First or second?

Comment: second, this inside ScrollView. First is unnecessary, lint propably is warning you about this (ofc if you really use static background color)

Comment: ~ Nevermind. There was a spelling mistake in the sv.getMeasuredHeight().

Comment: Still not scrolling :(. I'll google some more and update my answer when I get it working. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Your LinearLayout can't resize if the content is too long because you set a fixed size.

Just change :

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

by :

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Did that, it is expanded. But it won't scroll.

Comment: what is your layout/image_slider ?

Comment: It is a custom imageslider. Might be causing the problem if i think about it. I'll try some things with it.

Comment: No its not the problem. I changed it to NetworkImageView and a regular ImageView.

Comment: try to remove it just for testing but i'm pretty sure that is a conflict between image slider and scrollview

Comment: I used the scrollview on the lower LinearLayout with the text in it. Still not scrolling

Comment: if you just remove your include in your previous code, what happend ?

Comment: Wouldn't be long enough, so no scrolling at all. Trowing in an empty ImageView didn't scroll either. It was the layout_Weight attributes that killed the scrollview. Changed the layout_weight to layout_height = "wrap_contant/ 200dp"  etc.. This fixed it and the layout looks good enough, even on different resolutions.